# Xamarin reference management

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

My project architecture is like following for Droid,

Data access layer -> PCL Project -> Droid Project.

Now if I want to directly access any method for Data access layer in Droid project I need to add reference for Data Access layer to Droid Project.

Is there any way I can access method for DAL to Droid poject without adding it as a reference file?

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to bring in a service layer that lives inside your PCL

- DataAccess

  - SomeRepository : ISomeRepository
- PCL

  - ISomeRepository
  - ISomeService
  - SomeService : ISomeService
- Droid

  - ctor(ISomeService someService)

Your Service layer should be able to handle multiple repositories if necessary, and you have the added benefit of having a Service that talks to your DAL and another Service that talks to your API, both using the same interface.

```
// DAL
public class SomeRepository : ISomeRepository
{
    public void DoSomething(){
        // do something
    }
}
```

```
// PCL
public interface ISomeRepository
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public interface ISomeService
{
    void DoThings();
}

public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
    private ISomeRepository _someRepository;
    SomeService(ISomeRepository someRepository)
    {
        _someRepository = someRepository;
    }

    public void DoThings()
    {
        // do things via DAL
    }
}

public class SomeProxyService : ISomeService
{
    private HttpClient _httpClient;
    SomeProxyService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public void DoThings()
    {
        // do things via HTTP
    }
}
```